Calculating Bandgap of material from specular reflectance vs diffuse reflectance
I am looking for some clarification on whether specular reflection data can be used to calculate the bandgap of a material. I am using a UV-vis spectrometer and measuring the reflectance from an opaque crystal with a polished surface.
The route I see to this calculation is to use Tauc analysis where the absorption coefficient is realated to the Bandgap energy.
So I need to get the absorption coefficient from relfectance data. In examples I have seen, they use the Kubelka-Munk model to convert reflectance data into absorption data.
It seems like the Kubelka-Munk model is only valid with diffuse reflectance data.
I don't have an integrating sphere. Is there a way to do this calculation with specular reflectance data (for example, if I wanted to determine the bandgap of a silicon or GaAs wafer)?

Have you tried the Fresnel equations?

I'm an idiot. That's pretty obvious. I got it in my head from reading the literature that this more complicated process was required
